# #DIV/0! coming while evaluating correlation in MS-Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using MS-Excel for the first time to evaluate Correlation. To learn it I made two sequences of one as shown below:

[image]

I understand I have selected range correctly (as can be seen in the correlation dialog box), but still I am getting #DIV/0! (I am expecting 1 here as the sequences are 100% similar) as can be seen here:

Appreciate your help in solving the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [CORREL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/correl-HP005209023.aspx):

> If either array1 or array2 is empty, or if s (the standard deviation) of their values equals zero, CORREL returns the #DIV/0! error value.

Both of your arrays have a standard deviation of zero. Try changing at least one of the values in each array to something other than one and computing the correlation coefficient again.

Comment: Incidentally, from your screenshot it looks like you are using the data analysis add-in (basing that on [this](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/excel/ex51correlation.html)), so while I am answering using CORREL, it seems likely a zero standard deviation will manifest the same problem with the other approach. Please let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: your understanding is correct, I made the changes  and it worked perfectly well